# How to generate a well-formatted output of (all-ns) in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, pretty-print

I'd like to view the list of all namespaces. Therefore I use `(all-ns)`, which prints out a long list of namespaces.

Instead of having one namespace after another, I'd like to have each namespace in its own line. So, how can I printout a list in a way, that each item of the list is in its own line?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using CIDER, you can try toggle pretty printing: <kbd>M-x cider-repl-toggle-pretty-printing</kbd>.

And here is another solution:

```
(doseq [x (all-ns)] (println x))
```

or even:

```
(doseq [x (all-ns)]
  (println (ns-name x)))
```